# SSRS reports for multiple companies/teams

Tags: database-design, reporting-services

I'd like some advice on best practice.

I am maintaining an SSRS reports server, and now need to support multiple companies. Each company should only see their own data. And the parent-company should be able to see all data, but also be able to split by the child-companies.

Some of the reports are the same, just looking at different sub-sets of the overall data.

What is the best way to implement this, to ensure data is only accessible by the appropriate companies, and also that I can easily update reports, etc., and add new companies later on?

I'm currently building "core" reports, and then using linked reports with the company name as as a hidden default parameter.

Alternatively, I thought of creating individual databases for each company with the filtered views of the main data. So then instead of the parameter, I would change the Source.

I realize this is an open question, but would like to know the pros and cons from more experienced people, before setting on this.

Comment: How do you intend to have these companies access their reports?  VPN?

Comment: Some are within our network. The guys connecting from outside will be using VPN.

Comment: Do you expect the child-companies to have sublevels? (ABC-Management, ABC-Employee, ABC-peon, etc)?

Comment: Definitely. For the main child-company, I already have various folders (Management, Finance, Marketing, etc.). Each employee is part of the appropriate Windows group, and has access to only to the appropriate folder.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways you could approach this:

- Combined database and select by company
- Schemas within one database to separate the companies. A bit of maintenance required for this.
- Separate databases per company. Aggregation across companies may be complex.

Assuming this isn't a security issue for your internal people who have access to a combined database, the simplest is a combined database and have logic in the reports to ensure people only see the companies they are allowed to.

You have two issues here:

1. Identifying who is running the report
2. Identifying what companies they can run the report for

Reporting Services solves the first problem for you with the `@UserId` global variable.

I assume you have a table `Company` that looks like a bit like this:

```
CompanyId | Name        | ParentCompanyId
----------+-------------+----------------
1         | ABC Inc.    | 
2         | DEF Co.     | 1
3         | GHI Ltd.    | 1
4         | XYZ Corp.   |
```

We need a way of mapping that to the companies they can run the report for, so we create a table with `UserId` and `CompanyId` fields to map users to their company.

```
UserId    | Name        | CompanyId
----------+-------------+----------
10        | Alyssa      | 1
20        | David       | 2
30        | Gloria      | 3
40        | Xavier      | 4
```

So Alyssa can see ABC Inc and the subsidiary companies DEF Co and GHI Ltd, whereas David can only see DEF Co, Gloria can only see GHI Ltd and Xavier can only see XYZ Corp.

In your report you select your data based on the relationships:

```
SELECT Invoices.CompanyId, Invoices.Number, Invoices.Date, Invoices.Amount
FROM Invoices
INNER JOIN Companies ON Invoices.CompanyId = Companies.CompanyId
INNER JOIN Users ON Users.UserId = @UserId 
                AND ((Companies.CompanyId = Users.CompanyId) OR (Companies.ParentCompanyId = Users.CompanyId))
```

Okay, that takes care of making sure that the user can only see the data for the company and subsidiary companies that the user is associated with: David can only see invoices for DEF Co whereas Alyssa sees all invoices for ABC Inc, DEF Co and GHI Ltd.

Now, if Alyssa only wants to see DEF Co she needs to be able to select that company. Create a `@CompanyId` parameter based on this query:

```
SELECT Companies.CompanyId, Companies.Name
FROM Companies 
INNER JOIN Users ON Users.UserId = @UserId 
                AND ((Companies.CompanyId = Users.CompanyId) OR (Companies.ParentCompanyId = Users.CompanyId))
```

This shows all the companies the user can select. Set the default value of the parameter to get its value from a query:

```
SELECT CompanyId FROM Users WHERE UserId = @UserId
```

Then we just add this parameter to our query:

```
SELECT Invoices.CompanyId, Invoices.Number, Invoices.Date, Invoices.Amount
FROM Invoices
INNER JOIN Companies ON Invoices.CompanyId = Companies.CompanyId
INNER JOIN Users ON Users.UserId = @UserId 
                AND ((Users.CompanyId = Companies.CompanyId) OR (Users.CompanyId = Companies.ParentCompanyId))
                AND ((@CompanyId = Companies.CompanyId) OR (@CompanyId = Companies.ParentCompanyId))
```

**Report Subscriptions**

Now we come to delivering reports by subscriptions and our strategy around using `@UserId` falls apart because the report scheduler runs reports under its own account, not the user that we want to target.

Let's create a hidden parameter called `User` and make it the first parameter. For its Available Values property, create a query like the following:

```
SELECT UserId, Name
FROM Users
WHERE UserId = @UserId OR @UserId = 'MyDomain\ReportingAccount'
```

where `MyDomain\ReportingAccount` is the account that your reports run under. This query allows just the specific user details when an actual user is running the report but allows all users when the report scheduler is running it.

Make the Default Value property for your `User` parameter be `=User!UserId`. When your report scheduler runs the report, for the `User` parameter supply the UserId that you want for the person you are emailing.

Thus when the user runs the report, it selects the only possible user (which is themselves) and when the scheduler runs the report it selects the one you want from all available users. Being a hidden parameter, the user never sees it so doesn't know the difference.

If a user tries to be smart and spoof another user by passing it as a parameter in the URL it won't be a valid selection for the parameter's available values and so will fail.

Now just replace `@UserId` in the queries used above for company selection with `@User` and everything should work.

Comment: Thank you @Chris. I need to digest this a little. I did something similar for the languages that customer support have access to, and that's working nicely. One issue was report subscriptions. If I create report subscriptions for other people, it would use my user as the current user. (I don't Enterprise edition, so don't have the data driven subscription functionality.) So I would need a different version for emailed reports.

Comment: Also, just to confirm: This means that for each user, I need to create a Windows user on the server, and then also a database user with the same username. Correct? (And if the person is connecting from outside, our IT need to create a VPN user for him.)

Comment: For this method, they only need an authenticated Windows user on your network, which I assumed that they would have given they are VPNing in. You don't need to create a user on the actual SSRS server nor create a database user, but you will need to update your `Users` table to include the new user and indicate the company they can access. Obviously, your users should not be able to update this table.

Comment: I have a thought regarding subscriptions which is long, so I'll add it to my answer. I haven't tried this before myself (I wrote my own report scheduler/emailer) but it should work. Let me know how it goes if you try it.

Comment: Okay, I'll chat to my IT team about the Windows users. I've been maintaining my own users on the reports server. I'll check if we can start uniting the VPN and Reports Windows users. And I'll look at your solution for Subscriptions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would push the security implementation up a layer to the database, and force access through filtered views.  The usual technique is to build a table which lists the companies accessible to each user, then filtering views with an inner join to that table, using the CURRENT_USER function.

This is a more robust solution as it is not dependant on individual report parameter settings.  It will also support more deployment methods e.g. SharePoint, Web Apps, Excel etc.

With this in place, your Report Manager deployment becomes very simple - you can give all users the same access to a single set of folders and reports.

Comment: Thank you @Mike. I see Chris answered in a similar way in more detail. So I'll continue my questions/comments there.